# Text on header not appear in first page (PDF) using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a PHP that creates a PDF from DB data using FPDF library.

I use a header for show a title and logo. The logo shows correct in all pages, but the text not appear in the first page, only on others.

I use this function:

```
function Header() {
    $this->SetDrawColor(31,124,14);
    $this->Line(10,15,17,15);
    $this->Image('someLogo.png',20,10);
    $this->Text(100,25,"TITTLE");
    $this->Line(50,15,200,15);
    $this->Line(200,15,200,20);
    $this->Line(10,32,17,32);
    $this->Line(50,32,200,32);
    $this->Line(200,32,200,27);
    $this->Ln(50);
}
```

The lines draw something like a frame.

Thanks!

Comment: you know you can put header with $this->Cell(100,25,'Title',1,0,'C') function.. it will create all the lines for you..

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I miss to define typography for header text, then they get it from the table function and shows on next page...

Ty! ;D